# How to add a quick-add link to a related model in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-templates

Suppose there are two classes:

```
class A(models.Model): 
    …

class B(models.Model): 
    a = models.ForeignKey(A) 
    …
```

For the convenience to add a B without remembering the A, how can I add a link to add a B in A's change form?

Here is a solution mentioned in [this link](http://blog.robotercoding.com/?p=105), which suggest adding some codes in B's model, but I don't think codes like that should be placed in model.

Update:

The inline has a problem(or I don't do it right): when the number of inline objects exceeded the max_num attribute, there is no new blank form to add new objects. However, the number of inline objects could be very big.

Comment: You're probably looking for Inlines https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin which lets you add, edit, delete B objects from A's admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model A has a **reverse foreign key** to B, because B has a foreign key to A:

- B().a is a foreign key
- A().bet_set is a **reverse foreign key**

Django offers "**inlines**" to deal with **reverse foreign keys**.

1. In the context of forms in **user defined views**/*your code*, use [inline model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).
2. In the context of **Django admin**, use a [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) like *StackedInline* or *TabularInline*

If you do not want the inline formset to be generated from existing objects, then override the [queryset() method of your admin inline formset class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options), to return something like: YourModel.objects.none()

This will make the inline formset to be always empty. If you only want one extra form then set extra=1.

Comment: There is one problem bothering me for not using inlines, and I have updated the question.

Comment: If max_num is a limitation for you, why don't you remove it from your inline ?

Comment: But the number of inline objects could be tens of thousands... I just need a blank form...

Comment: have you thought of using extra = 1 and removing max_num?

Comment: @Meitham My problem is that the existed inline objects is too much, and I have to choose to display several of them. However, when I turn to the docs, they mentioned that the "max_num" will not limit the existed objects to be displayed-- they will be all showed. Moreover, when the objects exceeded the "max_num", the "extra" attribute doesn't work.

Comment: @jo32 the documentation does actually say that """The dynamic link will not appear if the number of currently displayed forms exceeds max_num...""" You could also see that in a comment in the django.forms.formset.py under total_form_count function.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset All you have to do is override the queryset method of your InlineModelAdmin class to return YourModel.objects.none(), and set extra=1.

Comment: No problem! If my answer solves your problem, then please click to "accept" the answer for organisational purposes. Thanks :)